# Why does the C++ stdlib rand() function give different values for the same seed across platforms?

Tags: c++, c, random, std

I understand that the `rand()` function generates pseudo-random numbers based on the seed it is given, and that on a given platform it will always generate the same sequence of numbers from the same seed, what I want to know is why it gives a different sequence across platforms that use the same library? I.e. how is `rand()` implemented?

Comment: Because the specification of `rand` does not dictate the values produced by sequence. Use [<random>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) if you want guarantees about the sequences.

Comment: The standard does not specify the sequence, or how the pseudo random number sequence is generated. So there is no restriction regarding implementation or behaviour across platforms concerning these two aspects. C++11 adds [random number generators with more specifications](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: Ok, I checked the standard and noticed that nothing is specified regarding the sequence, so on what factors does the implementation depend? Is it left up to the OS?

Comment: Actually this depends solely on the `libc` used.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I would have expected to find this in an answer.

Answer (score 21):

The C++ standard does not specify what algorithm is used for the rand() function.

The functionality is defined by whoever wrote the standard library on your system: Microsoft for the standard library included with Visual Studio, and the GNU guys for the standard library packaged with GCC.

Your compiler is making the choice of where it gets its library from, so you may have different versions of the standard library for different compilers on the same system. The point remains the same: the specification guarantees what functions are available and what they do; not how they do it.

Comment: Does that meant that running the GNU compiler on Windows will result in the same sequence?

Comment: @OmarKooheji I've actually never tried to install GCC on Windows. I believe GCC, when installed, comes with its own copy of the standard library (presumably pre-compiled). 

I don't know that for certain though - someone with access to a Windows PC that they can install stuff on should feel free to update my answer if true.

Comment: @OmarKooheji I was curious, so I investigated. Updated my answer to be a little more accurate (for the benefit of people trying to follow the comment thread in the future: I originally attributed the library to the OS, rather than your dev environment)

Answer (score 7):

> The rand() function shall compute a sequence of pseudo-random integers
>   in the range [0, {RAND_MAX}] with a period of at least 2^32.
>
> The rand_r() function shall compute a sequence of pseudo-random
>   integers in the range [0, {RAND_MAX}]. (The value of the {RAND_MAX}
>   macro shall be at least 32767.)
>
> If rand_r() is called with the same initial value for the object
>   pointed to by seed and that object is not modified between successive
>   returns and calls to rand_r(), the same sequence shall be generated.
>
> The srand() function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of
>   pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to rand(). If
>   srand() is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of
>   pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. If rand() is called before
>   any calls to srand() are made, the same sequence shall be generated as
>   when srand() is first called with a seed value of 1.
>
> The rand() function shall return the next pseudo-random number in the
>   sequence.

This is what that IEEE Std 1003.1 C-standard says about how the `rand()` function should behave. It doesn't say anything about how the sequence should be calculated. In other words, each implementer is free to choose their own version of a pseudo random sequence generator.

Your observations shows that they have taken advantage of that freedom.

*I might also point out that `rand()` is a part of the `<cstdlib>` which is more or less a copy of the C standard library , and the new  library will provide you with more flexibility and standard sequence generators if you have a new enough C++ compiler and doesn't depend on C - C++ interoperability.*

Comment: `rand` is also part of the C++ library, even though some parts of the standard are defined in terms of the C standard.

Comment: @phresnel, true, it did come across as it wasn't a part of c++. I have edited my answer to reflect what I meant.