# Does rand() function with the same seed gives the same random numbers on different PC's?

Tags: c++, random, cross-platform, seed, srand

I would like to know if I will get the same random numbers on all computers using the same srand() seed.

If not, how can I achieve that.

Comment: No, it is not guaranteed. Different implementations of the standard library can use different algorithms for pseudo-random number generation. If this is required, you can provide your own PRNG facility.

Comment: Another possible duplicate candidate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109427/why-does-the-c-stdlib-rand-function-give-different-values-for-the-same-seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `rand` implementation is not standartized and different compiler vedors can and will use different algorithms.

You can use generators from C++11 `<random>` header which are standard and completely determenistic: `mt19937` with same seed should give same sequence on all platforms, for example.